# Cannot install rust in ssh server

Tags: linux, rust

When I installed Rust on my supercomputer, I found the following error.

```
info: downloading installer

Welcome to Rust!

This will download and install the official compiler for the Rust
programming language, and its package manager, Cargo.

Rustup metadata and toolchains will be installed into the Rustup
home directory, located at:

  /home/~~/.rustup

This can be modified with the RUSTUP_HOME environment variable.

The Cargo home directory located at:

  /home/~~/.cargo

This can be modified with the CARGO_HOME environment variable.

The cargo, rustc, rustup and other commands will be added to
Cargo's bin directory, located at:

  /home/~~/.cargo/bin

This path will then be added to your PATH environment variable by
modifying the profile files located at:

  /home/~~/.profile
  /home/~~/.bash_profile
  /home/~~/.bashrc
  /home/~~/.zshenv

You can uninstall at any time with rustup self uninstall and
these changes will be reverted.

Current installation options:


   default host triple: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
     default toolchain: stable (default)
               profile: default
  modify PATH variable: yes

1) Proceed with installation (default)
2) Customize installation
3) Cancel installation
>1

info: profile set to 'default'
info: default host triple is x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: latest update on 2021-02-11, rust version 1.50.0 (cb75ad5db 2021-02-10)
info: downloading component 'cargo'
info: downloading component 'clippy'
info: downloading component 'rust-docs'
info: downloading component 'rust-std'
info: downloading component 'rustc'
info: downloading component 'rustfmt'
info: installing component 'cargo'
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 11, kind: WouldBlock, message: "Resource temporarily unavailable" }', /cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/threadpool-1.8.1/src/lib.rs:777:10
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
thread 'main' panicked at 'No process instance', src/currentprocess.rs:126:17
stack backtrace:
   0:     0x555555a35bc0 - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::libunwind::trace::h72c2fb8038f1bbee
                               at /rustc/7eac88abb2e57e752f3302f02be5f3ce3d7adfb4/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/libunwind.rs:96
   1:     0x555555a35bc0 - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized::h1e3b084883f1e78c
                               at /rustc/7eac88abb2e57e752f3302f02be5f3ce3d7adfb4/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/mod.rs:66
   2:     0x555555a35bc0 - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print_fmt::h3bf6a7ebf7f0394a
                               at /rustc/7eac88abb2e57e752f3302f02be5f3ce3d7adfb4/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:79
   3:     0x555555a35bc0 - <std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::DisplayBacktrace as core::fmt::Display>::fmt::h2e8cb764b7fe02e7
                               at /rustc/7eac88abb2e57e752f3302f02be5f3ce3d7adfb4/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:58
   4:     0x5555556bbdcc - core::fmt::write::h7a1184eaee6a8644
                               at /rustc/7eac88abb2e57e752f3302f02be5f3ce3d7adfb4/library/core/src/fmt/mod.rs:1080
   5:     0x555555a35461 - std::io::Write::write_fmt::haeeb374d93a67eac
                               at /rustc/7eac88abb2e57e752f3302f02be5f3ce3d7adfb4/library/std/src/io/mod.rs:1516
   6:     0x555555a34b74 - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::h1d14a7f6ad632dc8
                               at /rustc/7eac88abb2e57e752f3302f02be5f3ce3d7adfb4/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:61
   7:     0x555555a34b74 - std::sys_common::backtrace::print::h301abac8bb2e3e81
                               at /rustc/7eac88abb2e57e752f3302f02be5f3ce3d7adfb4/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:48
   8:     0x555555a34b74 - std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}::hde0cb80358a6920a
                               at /rustc/7eac88abb2e57e752f3302f02be5f3ce3d7adfb4/library/std/src/panicking.rs:208
   9:     0x555555a34b74 - std::panicking::default_hook::h9b1a691049a0ec8f
                               at /rustc/7eac88abb2e57e752f3302f02be5f3ce3d7adfb4/library/std/src/panicking.rs:227
  10:     0x555555a34690 - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::h2bdec87b60580584
                               at /rustc/7eac88abb2e57e752f3302f02be5f3ce3d7adfb4/library/std/src/panicking.rs:581
  11:     0x5555558d7853 - std::panicking::begin_panic::{{closure}}::h39dca43812dd462d
  12:     0x5555558d782c - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace::h9656b616b65c19d6
  13:     0x5555558d780a - std::panicking::begin_panic::h5586cbc30fc8be1e
  14:     0x5555558da0bd - rustup::currentprocess::home_process::h49d1d807786ac120
  15:     0x5555558d6b44 - rustup::cli::term2::stderr::h710a45d160fb3c78
  16:     0x5555558daca1 - rustup::cli::log::info_fmt::hbe1b619bf7b35d84
  17:     0x55555590b1b4 - rustup::cli::common::set_globals::{{closure}}::h13be3000d0ff61e3
  18:     0x55555591ed7b - rustup::toolchain::Toolchain::from::{{closure}}::hdd61529f737601f9
  19:     0x5555559835cd - core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::Fn<A> for &F>::call::hf2c4e1a974c3999d
  20:     0x5555559586be - core::ptr::drop_in_place::h866991d593ab0435
  21:     0x55555594436a - rustup::dist::manifestation::Manifestation::update::h49e35df33624591d
  22:     0x55555592e435 - rustup::dist::dist::update_from_dist_::h856b8e0b0136f3af
  23:     0x55555592b3a4 - rustup::install::InstallMethod::install::h7e8bcbc743b68843
  24:     0x55555592a140 - rustup::toolchain::DistributableToolchain::install_from_dist::h90ff519fb9ad8c7a
  25:     0x555555a20774 - rustup::cli::self_update::install::h0375248da3338fed
  26:     0x555555a26bd7 - rustup::cli::setup_mode::main::ha36cecb796fda7a9
  27:     0x555555641903 - rustup_init::main::hc72bdded9a9239cc
  28:     0x55555563e153 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h65ab0e0b87342893
  29:     0x555555642d95 - main
  30:     0x2aaaaaf09495 - __libc_start_main
  31:     0x55555563e029 - <unknown>
thread panicked while panicking. aborting.
sh: line 411: 118217 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) "$@"
```

Version 1.49.0 did not have this problem, but when I put in 1.50.0, I got this error.

My supercomputer has CentOS 7.5.1804 and RedHat Enterprise Linux 7.5.
Also, the CPU is AMD EPYC 7501.

Comment: `rustup` is failing to create threads because some sort of thread-related limit is being hit. Make sure `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max` is high enough, `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` is high enough. See the [full list of ways thread spawning can fail](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html#ERRORS).

Comment: You should consider creating an issue on the [rustup repo](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues), they're probably better at diagnosing the problem and you're more likely to get a fix.